# Why am I getting an ArrayIndexOutOfBoundsException in my code?

Tags: java

Why am I getting java.lang.ArrayIndexOutOfBoundsException :0 at CopyFile.main

```
//Copy one file Data to another File
import java.io.*;

class CopyFile{

        public static void main(String[] args)throws IOException{
            FileInputStream fis=new FileInputStream(args[0]);//reading File 
            FileOutputStream fos=new FileOutputStream(args[1]);//reading File
            int data;

            while((data=fis.read())!=-1){
                fos.write(data);
/*here  using while loop to copy data from one file and storing it in another file*/
            }
        }
}
```

Comment: Probably because you do not supply two arguments

Comment: Please post the complete error message so that we can see which line gives the error.

Comment: http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/getStarted/application/index.html

Comment: Sir, i request you please donot downvote me like this because i m new to java and i m trying to learn.Please i dont wanna get banned

Comment: You wont get banned because of one bad question. Just try to answer our questions from comments. Here people want to help you not punish you.

Comment: Now, now, nitin. a) Those who answer are clearly not those who downvote. b) copypasting comments like that is bad behavior in itself. Beginner's questions like yours get downvoted all the time, it's not a big deal. In the future work on improving the quality of your questions and show some signs of research prior to asking on SO. Also, cooperate better with those who are trying to help you. You didn't answer the questions posed in the comments below the question.

Comment: Sir i apologize for my past comment and thanx for the help .it seems i was executing the program without passing command line arguments.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It seems you are running the file as

```
java CopyFile
```

If you do so, its wrong. You should pass the arguments to run your code since your are looking for two arguments.

Run the code this way:-

```
java CopyFile arg1 arg2
```

Comment: Sir, i request you please donot downvote me like this because i m new to java and i m trying to learn.Please i dont wanna get banned

Comment: @NitinBansal: We are there to help but before posting a question or answering a question, you should go through the **[FAQs](http://stackoverflow.com/faq)** section, which will really helpful to you. For any problem, post a question with detailed information. It helps others to diagnosis your problem and tell you. Answer to your comment, I haven't downvoted.

Comment: thanx for the help .it seems i was executing the program without passing command line arguments.

Answer (score 3):

You probably don't pass two arguments in command line when you start application.

Comment: Sir, i request you please donot downvote me like this because i m new to java and i m trying to learn.Please i dont wanna get banned

Comment: I didn't downvoted you. If I would then I probably wouldn't answer your question.

Comment: thanx for the help u were right.it seems i was executing the program without passing command line arguments.

Answer (score 2):

You don't check to see of args is bigger than 2:

```
if (args.length < 2)
{
    // args[1] doesn't exist
    System.out.println("You didn't provide two files.");
    return;
}
```

Comment: Does not need to be bigger. Greater than or equal to two is fine

Comment: He doesn't have to check anything. He just needs to supply two arguments.

Comment: @MarkoTopolnik Even though checking is not needed for it to work, it would fix the exception and give a good error message.